# SMD Trimpot specs - some cite in K/M and others in uH

Tags: identification, surface-mount, components, specifications

Was searching for SMD trimpots at a popular online component site, and noticed that the search results were showing trimpots (s.a. from Bourns) some of whose 1-line specs read like they were variable inductors (since they mention something like 20uH, 200uH etc.), and others indicate that they are indeed variable resistors (mentioning value like 250K, 1M etc.)

Wondering if that is just a data-entry mistake / inconsistency, and that invariably all variable resistors will have some properties of an inductor, s.a. at high frequency (since they use metal coils) -- which might explain it!

Here's a screenshot of the search results:
[image]

By reading the specs (which seems to point to [same file](http://www.bourns.com/data/global/pdfs/3314.pdf) for all of these trimpots), the matter didn't clear up, at all.

Can someone please clear this up for me ?

Comment: This isn't a shopping list question. Not asking to recommend a part or anything. Not sure why this down-vote and vote to close. The last people can do while down-voting is leave a reason for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the pattern of the web sites´s product numbers and the linked datasheet I would say it´s definetly just a data entry error in the description field. [Individual item's web page](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/3314H-1-200/?qs=%2fha2pyFaduh7wkaYMcHTa2DpfOlNDVMiqB5%2fofuqkNuEuywEEAQgDg%3d%3d) shows the resistance I'd expect from the product number.

Comment: I agree; it makes no sense. It's made of the same stuff as the others: cermet.